# Function STRING_SPLIT in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I started analyze logs with T-SQL. I have one problem i can't deal with it.

Example message :

```
LogsID = "1" Value="1" Value="2" Value="3"
```

So I don't have problem with split this when I know how much I have Value, for example :

I use code from code section to split this data like below :

```
LogsID  Value
---------------    
   1      1
```

Code:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(1024);

SET @String = 'LogsID = "1" Value="1" Value="2" Value="3"'

SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(@String, 
              CHARINDEX('Logs_ID="', @String) + 11, 
              CHARINDEX('Value="', @String) - (CHARINDEX('Logs_ID="', @String) + 13))
```

But I don't know how deal with logs like below when I don't know how many "value" entries are in the log string:

```
LogsID = "1" Value="1" Value="2" Value="3"
```

I want split this information like that :

```
LogsID  Value
------------    
   1    1
   1    2
   1    3
```

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for instructions on how to ask a good question. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to find the types of information you need to post. As it sits right now this is not answerable.

Answer (score 11):

With a split function (there are many ways to do this prior to SQL Server 2016, here is one):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
(
    @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delim VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN ( SELECT [Value] FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT 
          [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
          CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
        FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
          FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
          WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
          AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
      ) AS y
    );
```

The query becomes simpler than a bunch of charindex etc. and an unknown endpoint:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(1024) = 'LogsID = "1" Value="1" Value="2" Value="3"';

;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT value, p = PARSENAME(value,1) 
  FROM dbo.SplitString(@String, 'Value=')
),
l AS
(
  SELECT LogsID = PARSENAME(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(value,CHARINDEX('=',value)+1,255)),1) 
  FROM x WHERE p IS NULL
)
SELECT l.LogsID,y.p FROM l
CROSS JOIN (SELECT p FROM x WHERE p IS NOT NULL) AS y;
```

Answer (score 0):

The STRING_SPLIT function in SQL Server is not available before SQL Server 2016, you should have at least compatibility level 130 as per Microsoft's docs.

Visit [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)
Below you can find a summary of each version and its compatibility level

| SQL Server Versions | Compatibility Level |
| --- | --- |
| SQL Server 2019 preview | 150 |
| SQL Server 2017 (14.x) | 140 |
| SQL Server 2016 (13.x) | 130 |
| SQL Server 2014 (12.x) | 120 |
| SQL Server 2012 (11.x) | 110 |
| SQL Server 2008 R2 | 100 |
| SQL Server 2008 | 100 |
| SQL Server 2005 (9.x) | 90 |
| SQL Server 2000 | 80 |