# How can I convert varchar (1,2,3) to a correlating column values name in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have an issue with converting a `varchar` column filled with id's (foreign keys) to another string with names, these names are linked in another table with their correlating id.

Data

```
 x-----x------------------------x
 | Id  | foreign Keys (varchar) |
 x-----x------------------------x
 |  1  |  1,2,3                 |
 |  2  |  2,3,4                 |
 |  3  |  4                     |  
 x-----x------------------------x
```

Names

```
 x-----x-----------------x
 | Id  |  Names (varchar)|
 x-----x-----------------x
 |  1  |  Rick           |
 |  2  |  Steven         | 
 |  3  |  Charly         |
 |  4  |  Tom            | 
 x-----x-----------------x
```

Basically I need the values in the table data to `UPDATE` to a varchar like 'Rick, Steven, Charly'.

I am working in SQL Server 2014, so I can't use the function `STRING_SPLIT`.

Help would be really appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I don't suppose there's any chance you could just fix the Data table to be `Id INT, NameId INT` instead of storing comma separated values?

Comment: As sqillman says don't make a headache for yourself if you can help it. There are ways to do it but it's cleverer to do it simply, the way SQL is supposed to work.

Comment: Yeah the thing is the table where I need to insert those values into which are comma separated is bit more complicated. The column has more options for values. It is an sort of collective of different kind of values.(ints, datetimes, strings). So I really I need the answer to the approach described as above.

Comment: Build a string_split in SQL 2014: [String_Split SQL2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618878/function-string-split-in-sql-server-2014) or [String_Split SQL2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902892/string-split-in-sql-server-2012)

Comment: Sounds like you need to really rethink your table design